# Helmotz Decomposition Inquiry

Tags: vector-analysis

In the composition:

$F = -\nabla \phi + \nabla \times A$

Why is there a negative in front of the gradient field? Is this always required?

Comment: It's a convention.  That's all.  It's introduced because in some applications,  $\phi$ is a potential.  Let $\psi=-\phi$ and you have eliminated the minus sign.

Comment: Just convention, really. It's not required - everything works just fine without it, as you could just define it to be a part of $\phi$. The reason it's there comes from Physics, where the force $F$ is the negative gradient of the potential $\phi$.

Comment: @tom Great minds and all ....